# KVM+Vagrant+ansibleで複数のVMを立てたい

Tags: vagrant, ansible

Vagrantで複数のVMをKVM上に作成し、ansibleで操作しようとしているのですがうまくいきません。
具体的な症状としては、

- 指定したIPアドレスが割り振られない
- SSHコネクションがタイムアウトする

を確認しております。
環境は
Vagrant:2.0.0
ansible:2.3.2.0
openssh:1.0.2k-fips
libvirtd:3.2

ネットワーク設定は、KVM標準のvirbr0を使い、192.168.1.0/24 <-> 192.168.122.0/24
のブリッジ接続をしております。

Vagrantfileは下記の通りです。

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :   

  config.vm.define :node1 do |t|
    t.vm.box = "centos7.3"
    t.vm.hostname = "node1"
    t.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.101"
  end
  config.vm.define :node2 do |t|
    t.vm.box = "centos7.3"
    t.vm.hostname = "node2"
    t.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.102"
  end


  # conf for ansible
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ans|
   ans.playbook = "ansible/vagrant.yml"
   ans.inventory_path = "ansible/hosts"
   ans.limit = "all"
  end


  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |lv|
    lv.management_network_name = "default"
    lv.management_network_address = "192.168.122.30/24"
    lv.storage_pool_name = "kvm_storage"
  end

end
```

ansibleのプレイブックとhostsファイルは下記の通りです。

ansible/vagrant.yml
    - hosts: vagrant
       remote_user: vagrant
       sudo: yes
       tasks:
         - name: yum install nmap
           yum: name=nmap

ansible/hosts
    [vagrant]
    192.168.122.101
    192.168.122.102

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

Vagrantの標準機能である、inventoryの自動生成機能を知らずホストを手動で指定していることが原因でした。

最終的に作成したVagrantfileとplaybookを添付します。

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.

  config.vm.box = "centos7.3"
  N = 2
  (1..N).each do |id|
    config.vm.define "host#{id}" do |node|
      node.vm.hostname = "host#{id}"
#      node.vm.network  "private_network", ip: "192.168.122.#{100+id}"

      if id == N
        node.vm.provision :ansible do |ans|
          ans.limit = "all"
          ans.playbook = "vagrant.yml"
        end
      end
    end
  end
   config.vm.provider :libvirt do |lv|
    lv.management_network_name = "default"
    lv.management_network_address = "192.168.122.30/24"
    lv.storage_pool_name = "kvm_storage"
  end
end




- hosts: all
   remote_user: vagrant
   sudo: yes
   tasks:
     - name: yum install nmap
       yum: name=nmap
```